# What is the symbol to show String concatenation in normal text?

Tags: symbols, string-concatenation

I want to know how to **show** the act of joining two names(strings) together. I am writing a pseudo code for a paper that has the string concatenation as part of it and I am not sure if there is any standard symbol to show that. Questions regarding the **String concatenation symbols** mostly addresses the syntaxes used to do the act of concatenation, but not the act itself.

For example, I have two variables ***A*** and ***B***, each with their specific names as ***"a1"*** and ***"a2"***, respectively (***A<sub>id</sub>=a*** and ***B<sub>id</sub>=a2***). Now I am creating a third variable ***C*** and I want to show that its name is ***a1a2***, what is the symbol for that?

***C<sub>id</sub> = A<sub>id</sub> (+?) B<sub>id</sub>***

Comment: Can you explain the supposed difference between “to do the act of concatenation” and “the act itself”? Besides that, there is no standard for pseudo-code.

Answer (score 0):

You could say something like `print.raw('text')`.